# Значение понятия "грёзы"

Tags: семантика

Могут ли человеку в грёзах представляться события мрачные, нежелательные, может ли понятие "грёзы" совпадать по значению с "бредом", "представлениями" или это всегда что-то желанное и мечтательное?

Answer (score 1):

Ефремова в своём словаре приводит это значение (бред во сне, сновидение) как устаревшее:

> Грёзы - 1. Что-л. желаемое, создаваемое воображением, возникающее в
>   воображении; мечты. 
>   2. устар. Сновидения.

http://tolkslovar.ru/g5411.html

В словаре Даля:

> ГРЕЗА -жен. мечта, блажь, мнимое видение, бред, игра воображенья во
>   сне, в горячке или наяву, при одностороннемнаправлении ума; речи во
>   сне, в бреду, в горячке; пустые, ложные речи, сказки и россказни,
>   болтовня, пустословие. | сиб. блажь, дурь, шалость. Греза •об. те же
>   понятия, перенесенные на лицо: кто грезит, бредит во сне, вгорячке, в
>   сумасшествии или при заносчивом воображении; | баловник, шалун,
>   затейник, проказник, кто дурит; врун. выдумщик, грезила. Грезить,
>   греживать что или чем, бредить, видеть во сне, в горячке; мечтать,
>   заноситься воображением, надеждами; пустословить, молотьвздор; шалить,
>   дурить, дурачиться, пакостить. Тебе это грезится, грезилось,
>   померещилось, привиделось, этомана, морока. Себе спит, на себя и
>   грезит. Молодец женится, а во сне ему грезится: не платить бы
>   попятного! Греженье •длит. действие и •сост. по гл. Грез муж., •об. то
>   же, бред, что грезится. От грезу не сбудется.
>
> Толковый словарь Даля. В.И. Даль. 1863-1866.

Видимо, в поэтическом смысле грезы - мечты, а если нужно сказать, что во сне ему пригрезилось - то вполне приемлемо и значение грезы-бред.